# (HTML or CSS) White background color is going lower than my last part of code

Tags: html, css

Hum, hey ! I got something that I tried to fix for almost four hours, but I couldn't find it. The worst thing is that i'm almost sure that it is a stupid thing to remove or to replace, but I don't know. So Is there is a way to make my background stopping on the last image or if it's a problem in my code, is there is a way to fix it?  I'm placing the code. Thanks in advance ! (my code may be horrible, sorry if that's the case ^^)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-fr">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>RealTea</title>
<style>
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 width: 1030px;
 height: auto;

}
#Menu {
 background-image: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429647024-liens.png');
 opacity: 0.9;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 1341px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: auto;
}

nav {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: Verdana;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
}
a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: Verdana;
 left: -80px;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
IMG.displayed {
 position: relative;
 left: auto;
 width: 1340px;
 
 }
p.newsletter {
 font-family: Homizio;
 font-size: 29px;
 color: #339900;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 left: 520px;
 bottom: -20px;
 width: 314px;
 height: 385px;
 }
p.Communaute {
 font-family: Homizio;
 font-size: 29px;
 color: #339900;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 left: 140px;
 bottom: 393px;
 width: 314px;
 height: 385px;
 }
p.inscription {
 font-family: Homizio;
 font-size: 29px;
 color: #339900;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 left: 908px;
 bottom: 808px;
 width: 314px;
 height: 385px; 
}
img.Bambou {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 680px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
img.nouveau {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 1090px;
 left: -600px;
 opacity: 0.6;
}
p.actu {
 font-family: Homizio;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 28.5px;
 color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.6;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 bottom: 1100px;
 right: -15px;
 width: 661px;
 height: 377px;
}
p.infos {
 font-family: Homizio;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 28.5px; 
 color: #339900;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 1600px;
 left: 120px;
 text-align: right;
}
p.plusinfos {
 font-family: Homizio;
 font-size: 29px;
 color: #339900;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 right: -780px;
 bottom: 1620px;
 width: 559px;
 height: 359px;
}
img.newlet {
 width: 399px;
 height: 68px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 1750px;
 right: -860px;
 }
p.newletter {
 width: 347px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Homizio;
 height: 32px;
 color: #000000;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 1821px;
 left: 780px;
 text-align: right; 
}
img.images {
 position: relative;
 left: 150px;
 right: 150px;
 bottom: -50px;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <nav id="Menu">
 <a href="#">Accueil</a>
 <a href="#">Forum</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/Ewan/Desktop/Travail%20Real%20Tea/Site%20entier.html#">
 <img class="displayed" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429658354-papierheaderfini.png" alt="jfl">
</a>
<div id="milieu">
 <img class="images" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429702366-thes.png" alt="tea" width="1050">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img class="images" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429703603-news.png" alt="selection" width="1050">
<p class="newsletter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at libero in magna commodo sodales. Maecenas diam nisl, elementum ut quam nec, pharetra auctor neque. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris imperdiet purus vitae pulvinar malesuada. Aliquam sit amet ligula sit amet dui aliquam lobortis. Morbi pretium nisl non risus fringilla fringilla. Proin ac lobortis mauris.</p>
<p class="Communaute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at libero in magna commodo sodales. Maecenas diam nisl, elementum ut quam nec, pharetra auctor neque. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris imperdiet purus vitae pulvinar malesuada. Aliquam sit amet ligula sit amet dui aliquam lobortis. Morbi pretium nisl non risus fringilla fringilla. Proin ac lobortis mauris.</p>
<p class="inscription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at libero in magna commodo sodales. Maecenas diam nisl, elementum ut quam nec, pharetra auctor neque. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris imperdiet purus vitae pulvinar malesuada. Aliquam sit amet ligula sit amet dui aliquam lobortis. Morbi pretium nisl non risus fringilla fringilla. Proin ac lobortis mauris.</p>
<img class="Bambou" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429706567-bambou.png" alt="lol">
<img class="nouveau" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429707724-nouveau.png" alt="nouveaut├⌐s">
<p class="actu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur egestas rhoncus auctor. In sed porta nisl, sit amet vestibulum massa. Etiam vehicula, magna et elementum faucibus, leo nulla bibendum eros, nec interdum magna nibh et ipsum. Duis fermentum, augue varius efficitur tincidunt, lacus elit egestas ex, ultrices hendrerit diam velit quis elit. Integer a sem in tortor eleifend lobortis. Nam mauris libero, varius eget dignissim eu, tempor id elit. In justo elit, molestie eu augue ut, pharetra interdum ipsum. Aliquam tincidunt euismod sem id euismod. Donec dui dolor,</p>
<p class="infos"> Plus d'infos sur nous :</p>
<p class="plusinfos">Pellentesque cursus convallis risus, vitae venenatis nibh tristique at. Maecenas imperdiet varius urna et consectetur. Quisque viverra dolor arcu, eu viverra arcu aliquam ut. Nullam suscipit mi quis erat gravida aliquet. Aenean et rutrum leo. Nulla facilisi. Sed posuere.</p>
<img class="newlet" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/17/1429709917-newsletter.png" alt="newlet">
<p class="newletter">Adresse mail :</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question there somewhere?

Comment: It's caused by combination or `relative position` and `bottom`. Hint: remove all `position` properties and try  it again without them.

Comment: Hey @Ewan.G, looks like this is your first question. We'll try to get you a good answer. I also want to suggest that you edit your post and specifically ask a question. You might also find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Well, that's the thing that I forgot to add and I don't know how to edit the question. So yeah, I'm gonna reformulate my sentence. The problem is "My background-color is going lower than my code, like, I can scroll my mouse lower than the last image, and there is only the white background showing." And my question is "Is there is a way to make my background stopping on the last image or if it's a problem in my code, is there is a way to fix it." Now it should me more clear, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem! It's hard when you're first learning a new website, like Stack Overflow.

Comment: P.S. There is an edit button in the bottom left corner of your question. I'll suggest an edit for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `position: relative;` to do things like placing images (using `<img>` tags) as backgrounds to some paragraphs of text. Trying to do things like that will just introduce problems.

You should use the built in functionality of HTML and CSS. A better way to do the background thing is to use the `background` CSS attribute on the `<p>` tag (or on a container element) and to avoid `position: relative;` completely.

For instance:

```
.my-text {
    background: #ddd url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 10px;
}

<div class='my-text'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum... some stuff...</p>
</div>
```

The real problem here is that there is no layout design on this webpage. The positions of the paragraphs are just hacked on there. I suggest going through some quick tutorials on HTML and CSS layouts. (Here is [an example](http://learnlayout.com) of one.)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with how all your elements are being positioned. For example the paragraph with class actu. It has a position: relative:

```
p.actu {
    font-family: Homizio;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28.5px;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: relative; /* Issue */
    text-align: left;
    bottom: 1100px; /* Issue */
    right: -15px; /* Issue */
    width: 661px;
    height: 377px;
}
```

Which actually means the element is still position "statically" on the page but you used bottom: 1100px and right: -15px to make it look like its visually not there. The browser will still recognize that the element is there along with all the element you visually moved. So if you look at the wrapper with id milieu its actual height is 3046px accounting for all the elements that's there just visually not.

The solution is as simple as removing all the position: relative, bottom, right, left, and top. Of course this will make your site look nothing like you intended. You need better practice on structuring your site.

Comment: Thank you ! The most annoying thing is gone now, And yeah I will practice on a other way. But that is a big step for me, thanks again.